# How to install specific package here or prevent the notice in apt?

Tags: debian, apt, software-updates

I update `apt` packages, and see that there is a package which can be updated because of the following notice.

```
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
```

Options are

1. to update to the version 
   `libreoffice-sdbc-firebird/stretch-backports 1:5.4.0-1~bpo9+1 amd64`.
2. to prevent the notice

Code to reproduce the notice

```
masi@masi:~$ sudo apt update
...
Hit:15 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
```

Seeing the list of packages where to choose the package to be updated and current status

```
masi@masi:~$ apt list -a --upgradable
Listing... Done
libreoffice-sdbc-firebird/unstable 1:5.4.0-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:4.3.3-2+deb8u7]
libreoffice-sdbc-firebird/stretch-backports 1:5.4.0-1~bpo9+1 amd64
libreoffice-sdbc-firebird/now 1:4.3.3-2+deb8u7 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 1:5.4.0-1]
```

### 1. Trying to update a package to unstable

Doing but conflicts so option (2) seems to be better

```
masi@masi:~$ sudo apt install libreoffice-sdbc-firebird/stretch-backports
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '1:5.4.0-1~bpo9+1' (Debian Backports:stretch-backports [amd64]) for 'libreoffice-sdbc-firebird'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-sdbc-firebird : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.4.0-1~bpo9+1) but 1:5.2.7-1 is to be installed
                             Depends: uno-libs3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but 5.2.7-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

### 2. To prevent this notice

I think it can be better to keep the current package but keep the notice for a while. 
Maybe with `equivs` and particularly `equivs-control`.

OS: Debian 9.1
Related: [Apt update says a package can be upgraded but upgrade says the opposit](https://askubuntu.com/q/921215/25388)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the `libreoffice-sdbc-firebird` (available only on stretch backports) you should upgrade the `libreoffice-core` and `uno-libs3` from backports.

```
sudo apt install -t stretch-backports libreoffice-core uno-libs3
sudo apt install -t stretch-backports libreoffice-sdbc-firebird
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the second line?

Comment: I already run the second command with `-t stretch-backports`. How can you revert back to stable `libreoffice-sdbc-firebird`? It says me `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-sdbc-firebird : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.4.0-1) but 1:5.4.0-1~bpo9+1 is to be installed Depends: libfbclient2 (>= 3.0.2~) but 3.0.1.32609.ds4-14 is to be installed` when trying to run the second command now.

Comment: `libreoffice-sdbc-firebird` isn't available for debian stretch (stable)

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy libreoffice-sdbc-firebird`?